# Nginx override Content type on Rails 4 X-Accel-Redirect urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, ruby-on-rails-4

I am sending some protected files in rails through `X-Accel-Redirect` via `nginx`.  I have been successfully running this setup for last 1 year(with rails 3), everything was fine.

My nginx.conf is

```
     proxy_set_header X-Accel-Mapping /var/www/app/current/public/restricted=/download_restricted/;
     passenger_set_cgi_param HTTP_X_ACCEL_MAPPING /var/www/app/current/restricted=/download_restricted/;
     passenger_pass_header X-Accel-Redirect;

     location /download_restricted {
        internal;
        proxy_cache editor;
        expires max;
        #add_header  Cache-Control public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=315360000";
        alias /var/www/app/current/public/restricted;
     }
```

and my rails code is

```
headers['X-Accel-Redirect'] = '/download_restricted/uploads/assets/'+ params[:asset_id]  + '/res/' + params[:res] + '.' + params[:format]
        headers['X-Accel-Expires'] = 'max'
        headers['Content-type'] = MIME::Types.type_for(params[:format])
        headers['disposition'] = 'inline'
        request.session_options[:skip] = true
        render :nothing => true
```

This setups is still working fine in rails 3 project. But rails 4 & nginx, content type is always coming as `text/html`.

I am serving audio/video/image files from the path. since the content type is coming wrong, browsers are not rendering the assets properly.

Is there a way in nginx to `set/overwrite the content type` of these requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting, it turns out that i have to pass `content_type` to `render :nothing` to make x-accel-redirect  to recognize content type and it doesnt care about `headers['Content-type']`

Now this code works fine

```
render :nothing => true, :content_type => MIME::Types.type_for(params[:format]).first.content_type
```